# Create flash video swf without an external control swf

Tags: flash, flvplayback

Creating a simple video for embedding by importing a video into flash creates a separate swf for the controls. Is there a way to have the controls embedded in the main SWF, so you don't have to worry about paths to the control swf?

Comment: why do you need TWO swf, when you can do all these tasks in ONE?

Comment: If we are talking about controlling from external components but in browser sandbox, you could use js wrapper which will communicate by ExternalInterface with your flash application.

Answer (score 0):

so you are doing something like this
http://www.webdesign.org/flash-swish/flash-tutorials/flash-cs5-flv-playback-video-tutorial.18633.html

but if you want dynamic url, you should code `init()` function which will get from e.g. FlashVars the needed url and put it inside of your VideoDisplay or FLVPlayer component and start playback.

So, please, clarify what are you looking for.

Comment: Yeah that's basically what I'm doing. What I want to know is if there's any way to package the controls in with the SWF so that I never have to worry about paths, or the additional file.